# javascript regular expression issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regular expression question.

I want the pattern match

```
01:20
```

The first 2 characters and the last 2 chracters have to be digits and the `:` is needed. Anything else will be 
invalided.

I have

`value.match(/\d\d:\d\d/)` but it doesn't match when I type `20:15`.

Did I do something wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: uh. it does match that... http://jsfiddle.net/nKptS/

Comment: @Otaia - a colon by itself is not a special RE character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression matches "01:20" just fine. The only thing wrong with it is that it will match things like "garbage01:20etc", which I gather you don't want. You need to use this:

```
/^\d\d:\d\d$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\b([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]\b
```

Comment: You're assuming that OP is processing 24-hour times. It may be simply proportions.

Comment: That's quite an assumption that he's validating HH:MM.